# is there a hash equivalent to a custom 'class variables'? (ruby)

Tags: ruby, scope, class-variables

I used hash of hashes to store settings in my code. I wonder if I can have something like class variable that is the same for all instances of the class for my @profile hash. So both profiles below would have general profile variable equal to both of them. I want the solution to **use hash**.

```
@profile = {
  "vB4Discussions" => {    #profile name
     "urls"  => ["vB4 General Discussions"],
     "process?" => false,
     "type" => 'Discussion'
   },
  "vB4Design".downcase => {          #profile name      
     "urls"  => ["vB4 Design and Graphics Discussions"],
     "process?" => false,
      "type" => 'Design'
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use a constant for the common bits, like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby1.8

require 'pp'

COMMON_PROFILE = {
  "urls"  => ["vB4 General Discussions"],
  "process?" => false,
  "type" => 'Discussion'
}

@profile = {
  "vB4Discussions" => COMMON_PROFILE,
  "vB4Design".downcase => COMMON_PROFILE,
}

pp @profile

# => {"vB4Discussions"=>
# =>   {"vB4Discussions"=>
# =>     {"urls"=>["vB4 General Discussions"],
# =>      "process?"=>false,
# =>      "type"=>"Discussion"}},
# =>  "vb4design"=>
# =>   {"vB4Discussions"=>
# =>     {"urls"=>["vB4 General Discussions"],
# =>      "process?"=>false,
# =>      "type"=>"Discussion"}}}
```

Comment: I got it, it took me some time but I understood :-) yes, that would one possible way. Let us see if somebody else can think of any other... Thank you Wayne

Comment: Keep in mind, this solution is only good if you won't be changing the configurations on the fly.  To find out why, Create this hash, modify one of the configurations: @profile['VB4Discussions']['type'] = 'chit chat' and then print the hash out.  When you understand what you then see, you'll know something important.

Comment: do you mean that modifying common bit will affect all configuration profiles? It seems to me that I will use your idea but in slightly modified way. I will add to all profiles new COMMON_PROFILE hash.

Comment: Yep, that's what I meant.  You're way ahead of me.

Comment: I wish I was :-)))))))))) I like your solution it is already implemented and working.Bit different though. I like the one below too.

Answer (score 4):

Did you know that hashes can have a special proc called when a key is not found?

This could be used here very nicely.

```
require "backports"  # Needed in Ruby 1.8.6
SETTINGS = {
  "default" => {
    "urls"  => [],
    "process?" => false,
    "type" => 'Discussion'
  },
  "vB4Discussions" => {
    "urls"  => ["vB4 General Discussions"],
  },
  "vB4Design".downcase => {
    "urls"  => ["vB4 Design and Graphics Discussions"],
    "type" => 'Design'
  }
}

# Use defaults 
SETTINGS["vb4design"].default_proc = lambda{|h, k| SETTINGS["default"][k]}
SETTINGS["vB4Discussions"].default_proc = lambda{|h, k| SETTINGS["default"][k]}

# Now the defaults are used if needed:
SETTINGS["vB4Discussions"]["type"]  # ==> 'Discussion'
SETTINGS["vB4Discussions"]["process?"]  # ==> false

# Defaults can be edited later:
SETTINGS["default"]["process?"] = true
SETTINGS["vB4Discussions"]["process?"]  # ==> true
SETTINGS["vb4design"]["process?"]  # ==> true

# Specific value can be changed too
SETTINGS["vb4design"]["process?"] = false # ==> true
SETTINGS["vB4Discussions"]["process?"] # ==> true
```

*Note:* Unless you have a valid reason to use strings, you should use symbols for your keys (i.e. `:vB4Discussions` instead of `"vB4Discussions"`.

The `Hash.default_proc=` is new to Ruby 1.8.7, so you need to `require "backports"` to use it. If you don't want this, you could instead specify the default proc when creating the hashes as follows:

```
DEFAULTS = {
  "urls"  => [],
  "process?" => false,
  "type" => 'Discussion'
}

SETTINGS = {
  "default" => DEFAULTS,
  "vB4Discussions" => Hash.new{|h, k| DEFAULTS[k]}.merge!{
    "urls"  => ["vB4 General Discussions"],
  },
  "vB4Design".downcase => Hash.new{|h, k| DEFAULTS[k]}.merge!{
    "urls"  => ["vB4 Design and Graphics Discussions"],
    "type" => 'Design'
  }
}
```

Comment: @Marc-Andre Lafortune: very interesting concept. Definitely answered my question.Pity I cannot use 'accept' twice.